# How to assign the real and imaginary parts of complex variables, individually, using the = operator in c++?

Tags: c++, geometry, variable-assignment, complex-numbers, assignment-operator

I'm trying to use the `complex<>` type to implement a Point class, for geometry problems.

I would like to be able to assign the value of the real and imaginary parts of the variable individually, through the `=` operand.

Like this:

```
class Point
{
public:
    complex<int> my_point;

    int& real(); // This should assign `my_point.real()` using `=`.
    int& imag(); // Same for `my_point.imag()`.
}

Point p;        // p is {0, 0}
p.real() = 10;  // p is {10, 0}
p.imag() = 20;  // p is {10, 20}
```

It would be very helpful being able to also retrieve these values using the same syntax.

```
cout << p.imag(); // p is {10, 20}, so this should print `20`.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: i never used complex, but thats not how you assign a value to a variable

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha I understand. The only way I found to modify the complex variable is to modify it whole: `p.my_point = {10, 20};`, or modify it through parameters in `real` and `imag` functions: `p.my_point.real(10)`. It would be very convenient to assign each part with the `=` operator though. I was hoping there is a way.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need a capsule? An overload? If you use `std::complex<T>` you already have all the natural overloads needed - as well as the member functions you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The capsule is so that I'll be able to implement some geometric algorithms in `Point`, while being able to still use the functionalities of the `std::complex<T>` variable. I still wouldn't know how to assign to the `real()` and `imag()` parts of `std::complex<T>`, individually, using the `=` operator even if there was no capsule in the first place, though.

Comment: @For `template<class T> struct mycapsule { T x, y; };` and then add member functions?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean, it works, but now I lose access to the `std::complex<T>` functions such as `arg` and `conj`, no?

Comment: @For Will your class be a holder of a complex number or will it _be_ a complex number? Decide on inheritance vs. composition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think both would work, but I see your point. I think I'm going to redo it as an inheritance, now that you've suggested it.

Comment: @For That answer is uncommon :-) If it _is_ a complex number, then just use the standard `std::complex`

Comment: Use std::complex<float>,  std::complex for integers is offcially not supported

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this answers your question:

```
class Point
{
public:
    std::complex<int> my_point;

    int& real()
    {
        return my_point.real();
    }

    int& imag()
    {
        return my_point.imag();
    }

    int real() const
    {
        return my_point.real();
    }

    int imag() const
    {
        return my_point.imag();
    }
};
```

then use the way you wanted to use it to either assign or get the value of the real and imaginary points. maybe like this:

```
int main()
{
    Point p;
    p.real() = 10;
    p.imag() = 20;

    std::cout << p.imag() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Just try it and let me know if it works or not

**Edit**
Since the previous attempt didnt work, i guess you'd need to cast it. i tried using reinterpret cast and it worked for me. Heres the code to what i tried:

```
//same code as previous
    int& real()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<int*>(&my_point)[0];
    }

    int& imag()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<int*>(&my_point)[1];
    }

    int real() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&my_point)[0];
    }

    int imag() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&my_point)[1];
    }
//remaining same code here as well
```

let me know about if it works or not for you, since it worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't compile. `my_point.real()` doesn't seem to work as a valid return type for the `int& real()` function. The same happens for `int& imag()`.

Comment: did you try casting it?

Comment: nvm im just gonna write an answer to it

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha `using Point = std::compex<int>;` would seem like a more complete implementation though.

Comment: Like i said, i dont know much about complex. For this answer, i just searched about the real and imag functions of std::complex and used operator overloading to just pass in some setters and getters . I was myself surprised that it worked.

Comment: It works, thank you! Now, if I may ask, what is the purpose of `reinterpret_cast<int*>` in the methods you made? I had tried to simply cast as you asked, and it hadn't worked.

Comment: if i must say, `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&my_point)[0]` means you're treating the memory of `my_point` as if it contains an integer and accessing the first part of it, which is the real part of the complex number. It was easy to just handle some arrays, as i was not really looking the complex numbers as "complex " numbers for this question. Id really like if you checked the answer as accepted.

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha What you know about complex (as a class or about complex numbers) doesn't matter really. Your answer adds nothing but complexity as I see it.

Comment: I was just making sure i dont get questioned too much about complex numbers. Im not gonna bother talking about it now

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha You missed the point. It has nothing to do with complex numbers.

Comment: That was how i was able to answer the question. . . .

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha I'm confused, but somehow your "anti"-answer helped OP. It's not going to be an answer that sticks with OP in the long run, but ok.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd respectfully disagree. Even if I were to use simply `std::complex`, or inherit it, I wouldn't still be able to assign the `real()` and `imag()` parts of `std::complex<>` with the `=` operator before this answer.

Comment: @For Sure you would. You just haven't decided if your class _is_ a or _has_ a.

Comment: Feel free to take the stuff in my answer and edit yours. Your initial approach is fine. If you do I'll up vote your answer.

Comment: the question is still the same

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha If you address someone, tag that person.

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha I downvoted to not let this answer be a template for future people searching for advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255296/discussion-between-shreeyash-shrestha-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 0):

Using [The exception that allows `constexpr` as shown here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) and adjusting Shreeyash's ideas:

> For any object z of type std::complex, reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0] is the real part of z and reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1] is the imaginary part of z

Just replace T's with `int` and drop the template if all you need is an int complex type.

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>  // floating point type
class Point
{
public:
    std::complex<T> my_point;

    T& real()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(my_point)[0];
    }

    T& imag()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(my_point)[1];
    }

    T real() const
    {
        return my_point.real();
    }

    T imag() const
    {
        return my_point.imag();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point<int> p;
    p.real() = 10;
    p.imag() = 20;

    std::cout << p.imag() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```